# Encoding Error while scraping a website using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape text from [this](https://www.onlinekhabar.com/2019/03/753522) website. It returns text like this:

```
à¤¡à¤¾. à¤­à¥à¤·à¤¬à¤¹à¤¾à¤¦à¥à¤° à¤¥à¤¾à¤ªà¤¾à¤²à¤¾à¤ à¤ªà¥à¤¤à¥à¤°à¥à¤¶à¥à¤, à¤à¤®à¥à¤°à¤¿à¤à¤¾à¤®à¤¾ à¤¤à¥à¤à¤¶à¥à¤°à¥à¤à¥ à¤¨à¤¿à¤§à¤¨
```

instead of:

```
भारतीय विदेश सचिव गोखले आज नेपाल आउँदै.
```

Current Code:

```
headers = {
        'Connection': 'close',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36',
    }

def get_url_soup(url):
        url_request = requests.get(url, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(url_request.text, 'lxml')
        return soup

soup = get_url_soup('https://www.onlinekhabar.com/2019/03/753522')
title_card = soup.find('div', {'class': 'nws__title--card'})
```

Comment: what is the type of title_cart? `str`?

Comment: Yes. Its a str. When I print it I get gibberish output. <span>à¥¨à¥¦à¥­à¥« à¤à¥à¤¤ à¥ª à¤à¤¤à¥ à¥§à¥¨:à¥§à¥¬ à¤®à¤¾ à¤ªà¥à¤°à¤à¤¾à¤¶à¤¿à¤¤ </span>

Comment: could you try `title_card.decode('utf-8')`, most probably it will work.

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: @BiratBadeShrestha see the answer posted below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`EncodingDetector`](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/96101/bs4.dammit.EncodingDetector):

```
from bs4.dammit import EncodingDetector

headers = {
        'Connection': 'close',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36',
    }

def get_url_soup(url):
        url_request = requests.get(url, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)
        http_encoding = url_request.encoding if 'charset' in url_request.headers.get('content-type', '').lower() else None
        html_encoding = EncodingDetector.find_declared_encoding(url_request.content, is_html=True)
        encoding = html_encoding or http_encoding
        soup = BeautifulSoup(url_request.content, 'lxml', from_encoding=encoding)
        return soup

soup = get_url_soup('https://www.onlinekhabar.com/2019/03/753522')
title_card = soup.find('div', {'class': 'nws__title--card'})

print(title_card.text)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
होमपेज / 
समाचार / 
राष्ट्रिय समाचार

भारतीय विदेश सचिव गोखले आज नेपाल आउँदै
प्रधानमन्त्रीलगायत शीर्ष नेतासँग भेट्ने 
.
.
.
```